Ellipsoid name from semi-major axis and flattening
If I have values for the semi-major axis and inverse flattening of an ellipsoid, is there a web-based tool through which I can find its name, and possibly a full authority description? I know of the API on epsg.org but that requires me to know the authority code.
As an example: semi-major axis with value 6,378,388 and inverse flattening of 297. (International 1924) should return EPSG:7022 or a full WKT.

Could you add the values so I can test?

@user30184 Added an example

I do not know any web-based tool, but the Proj library comes with a "proj.db" database that contains all information that you need and it can be queried with standard SQL.
Basically the proj.db database is a copy of an EPSG database with some Proj specific extras. Proj can be installed separately but it comes also shipped with QGIS, GDAL and many other software so maybe you have it already available.
Because the proj.db file is an SQLite database it can be opened and queried with any SQLite client (program or library). In the following example I use the DB Browser for SQLite program.
This image shows the structure of the "ellipsoid" table:

Build the SQL query:
select auth_name,code, name from ellipsoid
where semi_major_axis=6378388
and inv_flattening=297;

And get the result:

I do not know well enough how to build a valid WKT presentation from the parameters of the ellipsoid, but Proj has an utility "projinfo" https://proj.org/en/9.4/apps/projinfo.html that can do that when the authority code is known. Usage example:
projinfo -k ellipsoid -o WKT2:2019 EPSG:7022
WKT2:2019 string:
ELLIPSOID["International 1924",6378388,297,
    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
    ID["EPSG",7022]]

